# What Principles of Physics or Fluid Dynamics Explain Why Water Drains Slowly from a Funnel?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

When I pour water into/through a funnel, it easily and quickly goes into a vortex flow and drains slowly. I can break the vortex to make it drain faster by redirecting the flow of water into the funnel.  I am puzzled why the water tends to go into a configuration that slows the flow.

I would think that nature might maximize the rate of loss of potential energy of the water, but this is not the case.  What principles describe this phenomenon?

Comment: In the situation you describe the reason is the (approximate) conservation of angular momentum. (Of course some angular momentum is transferred by friction to the funnel which is assumed to be static, therefore the angular momentum of the fluid is not exactly conserved).